# Proof that $|f(x)-f(y)| \leq V_{x}^{y}(f)$

Tags: real-analysis

I want to show that for all $x, y \in [a, b]$ we have that $$|f(x)-f(y)| \leq V_{x}^{y}(f)$$, from where $V_{x}^{y}(f)$ represents the total variation of $f$ in $[x, y]$.

So my initial question starts from here, should I start with a partition of $[x, y]$ or $[a, b]$ ?, I think that we need a partition of $[x, y]$ say $P=\{a, y, x, b \}$ s.t. for all $x, y \in [a, b]$ we have that

$$V_{x}^{y} =\sup_{P} \{V_{p}(f) \} \geq |f(x)-f(y)|$$

The result seems clear from this point of view, but I am not entirely sure. Any suggestions?

Comment: $P=\{a, y, x, b \}$ is not a partition of $[x, y]$.

Comment: In this case, What could be the candidate for partition?

Comment: What about $P=\{x, y\}$?

Comment: @MartinR Sure, it's ideal. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I'll assume that $x \le y$ so that $V_x^y(f)$ is defined.)

$P=\{x, y\}$ is a partition of $[x, y]$, and therefore
$$
V_x^y(f) \ge V_P(f) = |f(y) - f(x)| \, .
$$

Actually, for *all* partitions $P=\{ x_0, x_1, \ldots x_n \}$ of $[x, y]$ is
$$
V_x^y(f) \ge V_P(f) = \sum_{k=1}^n |f(x_k)-f(x_{k-1})| \ge \left|\sum_{k=1}^n (f(x_k)-f(x_{k-1})) \right| = |f(y) - f(x)|
$$
because of the triangle inequality.